# Multiple Schema.org telephone values

Tags: microdata, schema.org

Is it okay to have more than one telephone value when using the suggested Schema.org markup?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
   <span>Office:<span itemprop="telephone"><a href="tel:00123456789" itemprop="telephone">00123456789</a></span></span>
   <span>Telephone:<span itemprop="telephone"><a href="tel:0987654321">0987654321</a></span></span>
   <span>Email:<a href="mailto:jane-doe@xyz.edu" itemprop="email">jane-doe@xyz.edu</a></span>
</div>
```

I couldn't find specific item types for "Office" or "Mobile".

Comment: Did you test it here? https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ Its not pulling telephone # at all.

Comment: Good shout. I've changed the above markup and both telephone numbers validate.

Comment: Good deal, looks good. It validates, you can use multiple telephones, or you can try the `contactPoint` if you need more infos for each, like defining 1 for mobile and 1 for home or something.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I've also updated my question for anyone wanting to add labels e.g. "Office:".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, providing the property multiple times is the correct way to do this in Microdata.

If you want to provide data about the telephone number, you could use the [`contactPoint`](http://schema.org/contactPoint) property with a [`ContactPoint`](http://schema.org/ContactPoint) value for each telephone number. Its [`contactType`](http://schema.org/contactType) property could specify the kind of contact point (e.g., "Office" or "Mobile").

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">

  <div itemprop="contactPoint" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPoint">
    <div><span itemprop="contactType">Office</span>: <a href="tel:00123456789"><span itemprop="telephone">00123456789</span></a></div>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="contactPoint" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPoint">
    <div><span itemprop="contactType">Mobile</span>: <a href="tel:0987654321"><span itemprop="telephone">0987654321</span></a></div>
  </div>

</div>
```